# DisambiguationError and GuessedAtParserWarning in Wikipedia API in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I want to get a list of possible and acceptable names that Wikipedia has related to the search term. "Corona" in this case.
When typing this:
`print(wikipedia.summary("Corona"))`

This is giving an output of:

```
/home/virej/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py:389: GuessedAtParserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 389 of the file /home/virej/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="lxml"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor.

  lis = BeautifulSoup(html).find_all('li')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/virej/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wikipedia/util.py", line 28, in __call__
    ret = self._cache[key] = self.fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/virej/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py", line 231, in summary
    page_info = page(title, auto_suggest=auto_suggest, redirect=redirect)
  File "/home/virej/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py", line 276, in page
    return WikipediaPage(title, redirect=redirect, preload=preload)
  File "/home/virej/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py", line 299, in __init__
    self.__load(redirect=redirect, preload=preload)
  File "/home/virej/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py", line 393, in __load
    raise DisambiguationError(getattr(self, 'title', page['title']), may_refer_to)
wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError: "Corona" may refer to: 
Stellar corona
Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2
Coronavirus disease 2019
COVID-19 pandemic
Corona (beer)
cornice
The Corona, Canterbury Cathedral
Corona (fictional world)
Doraemon: Nobita to Mittsu no Seireiseki
Spider Riders
Tangled
Super Mario Sunshine
Corona (novel)
Paul Celan
Samuel R. Delany
Corona (band)
cantus
```

Followed by more of these names.

I want just the list of the names and not the `GuessedAtParserWarning` or the `DisambiguationError`

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, install the module from the PyPI using `pip install wikipedia`.
Once installed the module `import wikipedia`
Then `print(wikipedia.summary("Corona"))`

If you have fulfilled the above requirements and still the error happens do the following

```
import warnings

warnings.catch_warnings()

warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
```

still, the error has occurred
use exception handling:

```
try:
 print(wikipedia.summary("Corona"))
except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
  print(e.options)
```

Comment: Okay, do this
`import warnings

warnings.catch_warnings()

warnings.simplefilter("ignore")`

Comment: This is still not working. It is throwing the same errors and warnings as before

Comment: @VirejDasani try this: 

`try:

 print(wikipedia.summary("Corona"))

except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
  print(e.options)`